# How to concatenate two videos that have different width and height with ffmpeg without duplicating many frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatenate two videos together but everytime I do it the process never finishes and takes forever. I also get many warnings like and also `Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it. Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2`

This is the command I run

```
ffmpeg -i /tmp/test-video.mp4 -i /tmp/test-video-1.mp4  \
                            -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920:1080[0v],[0v]setsar=ratio=1920/1080[0vf]; [1:v]scale=1920:1080[1v],[1v]setsar=ratio=1920/1080[1vf];  \
                            [0vf][0:a][1vf][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
                            -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -preset ultrafast res.mp4
```

This is the log of running my command

````
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/tmp/test-video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:32.79, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1566 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1434 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/tmp/test-video-1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.06, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 805 kb/s
  Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1020x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 17:12], 671 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in0:a0
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> scale
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat:in1:a0
  concat:out:v0 -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0x7ffb1e830400] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
[libx264 @ 0x7ffb1e838e00] using SAR=16/9
[libx264 @ 0x7ffb1e838e00] MB rate (8160000000) > level limit (16711680)
[libx264 @ 0x7ffb1e838e00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7ffb1e838e00] profile Constrained Baseline, level 6.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
# more logging hidden
More than 1000 frames duplicated      0kB time=00:00:00.25 bitrate=   1.5kbits/s speed=5.32x    
More than 10000 frames duplicated   1280kB time=00:00:00.32 bitrate=32257.2kbits/s dup=39998 drop=0 speed=0.00393x    
```
````

Comment: What if you scale the videos independently and then concatenate them? I guess that if you transform your videos first to an standard output for both you should not have any problem when you want to concatenate them.

Comment: Okay I'll try that, the reason why I do this is that I want it to be as fast as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I solved it was I added their suggestion but instead of adding `-vsync 2` so the entire command becomes

```
ffmpeg -y -i /tmp/test-video.mp4 -i /tmp/test-video-1.mp4 -filter_complex \ 
"[0:v]scale=1920:1080[0v],
[0v]setsar=ratio=1920/1080[0vf]; [1:v]scale=1920:1080[1v], \
[1v]setsar=ratio=1920/1080[1vf];[0vf][0:a][1vf] \
[1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
-map [v] -map [a] -vsync 2 -preset ultrafast res.mp4
```